# Cyclicality of Markups

Tags: macroeconomics, reference-request

I'm looking for scholarly articles or summaries on the subject of markups. More importantly, for empirical evidence whether they're pro- or counter cyclical, and on theoretical papers on their conclusions.

For Example, *Nekarda and Ramey, [The Cyclical Behavior of the Price-Cost Markup](http://www.nber.org/papers/w19099)*, who show that some methods which provide empirical counter cyclicality are not robust, and look at the implications for Neo Keynesian models.